# responsive file manager integrated with Tinymce cannot open dialog box

Tags: tinymce, file-manager

When I click the browse button, I got error like this

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

**Can someone please tell me what is going wrong?**

Comment: maybe you should provides some more information of what do are doing and what you tried so far

Answer (score 0):

'$ is not defined' is the jquery error, you should try after including jquery min file in you code.

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```